# dilution of Calcium Hydroxide

Tags: solutions

I have a 30% solution of Calcium Hydroxide.  I want to make a 1% solution.  How would I go about doing this?  I tried using C1 x V1 = C2 x V2

Comment: How about you show your calculation as your approach seems to be right

Comment: You can't possibly have a 30% solution of calcium hydroxide. Other than that, your approach is right.

Comment: right formula, wrong reality. I agree with Ivan.

Comment: @user65526 Welcome to chemistry SE! If you haven't yet, take the [tour] and visit the [help]. I would agree with Avnish, try to write up your attempt using Mathjax and then other users can fix any formatting issues to show you how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s imagine you have 10 mL of this 30% $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ solution. You are right to plug into the equation that you specified.

$$C_1*V_1 = C_2*V_2$$

$$30\%*10 mL = 1\%*V_2$$

$$\begin{split}
V_2 & = \frac{30\%*10 mL}{1\%}\\
& = 300 mL
\end{split}$$

This means that the final volume will be 300 mL. However, since there are already 10 mL of solution, you only need to add 300 mL - 10 mL = 290 mL of solution.

Comment: I'm glad you started off *Let’s imagine...*. Wikipedia list solubility as 1.73 g/L (20 °C). That's a long way from a 30% solution. // You're also wrong that you could add 290 ml water and 10 ml 30% Ca(OH)2 and get 300 ml of solution. You'd need to take 10 ml of base and dilute to 300 ml.

Comment: @MaxW :) (characters needed)

Comment: @MaxW Your comment is confusing me: What's the difference between 10 ml 30% Ca(OH)2 and 10 ml base?

Comment: None. You'd of course need "about" 290 ml of water. But as an analytical chemist I was trying to point out that volumes aren't really additive. I greatly prefer to think of diluting the 10 ml to 300 ml total rather than adding 10 ml and 290 ml to get 300 ml.

Comment: Ivan and Max W it is a 30% solution, which of course is mixed constantly.

Comment: @user65526 Good to hear! Is there anything else I can help with? If not, would you mind accepting my answer by clicking the check mark in the upper-left of my answer? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: If the Ca(OH)2 isn't totally dissolved then there isn't a "solution" but a "mixture."

Comment: true.  Sorry for putting solution